# The sparsest planar net that captures every unit segment

Tags: reference-request, mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, plane-geometry, tiling

Let $\cal C = \lbrace C_i \rbrace$ be a collection
of rectifiable curves in the plane with the property that
every unit-length segment meets at least one curve
in at least one point.
Call such a collection $\cal C$
a *needle net*: any unit-length "needle" is captured by the net.

I would like to find the sparsest needle net, sparse in the
sense that the curves have minimum length per unit area.
That is, the limit of $L/A$ of the ratio of the length $L$ of the curves within a region
to that region's area $A$, as the region grows large, is as small as
possible.

For example, a regular grid of orthogonal parallel lines
separated by $\sqrt{2}/2$ is a needle net: the diagonal of
each square cell of the grid has length $1$.
If I've calculated correctly, the length of its
curves (lines) within each unit area region $L/A$ is $2 \sqrt{2}$.
See left below, where a unit-length
diagonal is highlighted in red, and the region of the plane
I used to compute $L/A$ is marked.

   [image: Three Meshes]

Again if I've calculated correctly, the equilateral-triangle tiling of
the plane obtained from three sets of parallel lines is less efficient,
and the packing arrangement of unit-diameter circles shown right above
is less efficient still.

Is the square-grid the sparsest needle net?
This feels like a question that has been addressed before, perhaps
in another guise.  If so, a pointer would be welcomed.
Thanks!

**Update**. Roland Bacher's more efficient needle net:

            [image: Hex Tiling]

Is this the optimal net?

Comment: I've given up trying to work out what it gives you, but you can move the circles in the right hand figure further apart for a small saving.  It doesn't look like it will beat the square lattice though.

Answer (score 11):

Without error of my part, a paving with regular hexagons with sides of length $1/2$ gives 
$L/A=4\sqrt{3}/3\sim 2.3094$. This could very well be the optimal candidate.

Comment: Since it is Steiner tree like, I imagine you have hit it.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2012.11.16

Comment: @Roland: Very nice improvement! Now the challenge would be to prove this is the (unique?) minimal net... 

Comment: It may be not hard in the class of "decent" nets (tilings by convex polygons, say). Just try the argument a la Fejes Toth for planar packings. However, I suspect some monsters may be lurking there...