# "a shape that ... lies halfway between a square and a circle"

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, computational-complexity, tiling, isoperimetric-problems

An article in the
*Notices of the AMS*, Volume 61, Issue 10, 2014
([PDF download link](http://www.ams.org/notices/201410/rnoti-p1240.pdf)),
on Khot's Unique Games Conjecture, says this:

> Another group ... found a 
>   shape that in a certain sense lies halfway between 
>   a square and a circle (though in many more than 
>   two dimensions). 
>   Like a square, copies can be placed next to 
>   each other horizontally and vertically to fill a 
>   whole space without gaps or overlaps, forming a 
>   multi-dimensional foam. But its perimeter is much 
>   smaller than a square—it’s closer to that of a circle, 
>   the object which has the smallest perimeter for the 
>   area contained.

Could someone please either explain this enigmatic description further,
or provide a reference to the original work? Thanks!

(This issue is related to my earlier [answered] question,
"[Optimal planar net for catching convex shapes](https://mathoverflow.net/q/185856/6094).")

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is work by Guy Kindler, Ryan O’Donnell, Anup Rao, and Avi Wigderson, published in [Spherical Cubes and Rounding in High Dimensions](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~odonnell/papers/spherical-cubes-conference.pdf) (2008), and in [Spherical Cubes:
Optimal Foams from Computational Hardness Amplification](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~odonnell/papers/spherical-cubes-journal.pdf) (2012).

[image]

> Foam problems are concerned with how one can partition space into
>   "bubbles" which minimize surface area. We investigate the case where
>   one unit-volume bubble is required to tile $d$-dimensional space in a
>   periodic fashion according to the standard, cubical lattice. While a
>   cube requires surface area $2d$, we construct such a bubble having
>   surface area very close to that of a sphere; i.e., proportional to
>   $\sqrt d$ (the minimum possible even without the periodicity
>   constraint). Our method for constructing this "spherical cube" has a
>   surprising inspiration: foundational questions in the theory of
>   computation—specifically the issue of "hardness amplification". We
>   additionally show an algorithmic application of our new foam: a method
>   for "coordinated discretization" of high-dimensional data points which
>   has near-optimal resistance to noise. Finally, we provide the most
>   efficient known cubical foam in 3 dimensions.

Comment: Since my [suggested edit](http://mathoverflow.net/review/suggested-edits/31147) was rejected, I'll just point out in a comment that it is preferred to embed images using the editor/imgur instead of using external links to prevent link rot (as discussed [on meta](http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1012/inline-images-not-displaying-correctly#comment4508_1020)).

Answer (score 12):

Just to supplement Carlo's answer with a figure
that illustrates this intermediate cube-sphere shape in $\mathbb{R}^3$, 
from [the 2012 paper](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~odonnell/papers/spherical-cubes-journal.pdf)
he cites—"we provide the most 
efficient known cubical foam in 3 dimensions":

---

[image: SCubesFig5]

---